# How echo data from 3 different databases after selection?

Tags: php, mysql

Have 3 tables called "table1" "table2" and "table3". Only the column id is same in these tables. All other columns are different.

Will select like:

```
 "select * from table1, table2, table3 where WHERE (date >= now())";
```

I am facing problem while echoing the data. The table1 have one column called "org", table2 have "name", table3 have "pgm". I want something like:

```
 echo "$data['org']" OR $data['name'] OR $data['pgm']"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried learning SQL ?

Comment: Just do 3 selects bro, you can't join tables that have no correlation.

Comment: What data joins the 3 tables?

Comment: It doesn't, that's why it's not possible.

Comment: We do not know that for certain although it is likely

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming what you said is true:

> Only the column id is the same in these tables

Then you can join the tables that share this column value and retrieve the values back in a query:

```
SELECT       t1.org,
             t2.name,
             t3.pgm
FROM         table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON         t2.id = t1.id
  INNER JOIN table3 t3
  ON         t3.id = t1.id
WHERE        t1.date >= NOW();
```

An explicit join, but further illustrates the relationship the tables must have when collecting data from different sources.